# Routing Automaton

Tags: automata, regular-language

Is there a formal proof for the following question?

> For a DFA $M= (Q,\Sigma,\delta,s,A)$, we extend the function $\delta : Q  \times  \Sigma^* \to Q$, such that every $w \in \Sigma^* $, $\delta(q,w)$ is the individual $q'$ such that $(q,w) \to^*M (q',\epsilon)$. Given a DFA $M= (Q,\Sigma,\delta,s,A)$, we say that a word $w \in \Sigma^* $ is *routing in the automaton $M$* if there is a $q \in Q$  such that for every $q' \in Q$ $\delta(q',w) = q$. An automaton $M$ having a routing word, is called a *routing automaton*.
>
> Prove that every routing automaton $M$ with $k$ states has a routing word of length at most $k^3$.
>
> Hint: what you can say about the length of the words the routes 2 states into a single one?
>
> UPDATE  - I think that if i can show that there is a word w, |w| <= $k^2$ that routes 2 states into a single one, then I can build a routing string from this words where the length is at most $k^3$

thanks!

Comment: What does it mean by $\to^*$ ? If $M$ is deterministic, there is only one $q'$ such that $\delta (q,w) = q'$. What do you mean by individual?

Comment: @scaaahu I'm sorry, but I don't know exactly what the extension means. You are right that in simple deterministic $\delta(q,w) = q'$, so I'm not sure. Maybe it is just the formal explanation.

Comment: also I found, Q 1.59 :http://books.google.co.il/books?id=1aMKAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA92&dq=prove+that+if+m+is+k-state+synchronizable+dfa+it+has+a+synchronizing+sequence+of+length+k3&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tqGhUoTnM6mM7Ab62IGADQ&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=prove%20that%20if%20m%20is%20k-state%20synchronizable%20dfa%20it%20has%20a%20synchronizing%20sequence%20of%20length%20k3&f=false

Comment: @scaaahu: $\delta ( q, w )$ is the final state reached by the DFA $M_q = \langle Q , \Sigma , \delta , q , A \rangle$ when given input $w$ (only changed the starting state).

Comment: @ArthurFischer I am not sure the routing automata here is different from synchronizable DFA in Exercise 1.59 of Sipser's book. If they are the same, I think this is a homework problem.

Comment: @scaaahu: They're exactly the same (just different names).

Comment: @ArthurFischer Have any clue about the solution? thank you.

Comment: @scaaahu: The plain arrow ($\to$) indicates a single transition; $\to^*$ indicates any non-negative number of transitions. Here it indicates $|w|$ transitions. And I suspect that it should read $(q,w)\to_M^*(q',\epsilon)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I know it has something to do with "Synchronizing Sequences", "reset sequence" and "Jan Černý conjecture"

Comment: also http://books.google.co.il/books?id=OBWD2hj6GgIC&pg=PA234&lpg=PA234&dq=reset+sequence+bound&source=bl&ots=t0R-IHZeE7&sig=CCxxHaH982ddk8lYhlhAAn_Qb-c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=X-ShUsPWKuSk0QXV4IH4Dg&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBA#v=snippet&q=%22The%20reset%20sequence%20found%20by%20algorithm%22%20&f=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the hint, suppose that $q, q^\prime \in Q$ are distinct, and $w \in \Sigma^*$ routes $q$ and $q^\prime$ to the same state, that is, $\delta ( q,w ) = \delta ( q^\prime,w )$.  If $\mathrm{length}(w) > k^2$, consider the pairs of the form $$\langle \delta (q,w_0) , \delta (q^\prime ,w_0 ) \rangle$$ where $w_0$ is an initial segment of $w$  Note that there are only $k^2$ different pairs of states of $M$, and so there are distinct initial segments $w_0 , w_1$ of $w$ such that $$\delta (q,w_0) = \delta (q,w_1) \;\text{and}\;\delta (q^\prime,w_0) = \delta (q^\prime,w_1).$$
Assuming that $w_0$ is the shorter initial segment, we may write $w$ as $w_0 v u$ where $w_0 v = w_1$.  A simple argument will now show that $\delta (q, w_0 u ) = \delta ( q^\prime , w_0 u )$ ($= \delta ( q , w ) = \delta ( q^\prime , w )$).

It follows that if $q,q^\prime$ are states *routable* to the same state by some word, then there is a word of length $\leq k^2$ which witnesses this (and also attains the same final state).

---

Now suppose that $M$ is routable with final state $p$.  Enumerate the other states of $M$ as $\{ q_1 , \ldots , q_{k-1} \}$.  We will inductively construct our word $w$ as follows:

- Note that $q_1 , p$ are routable to $p$, and so by the above there is a word $w_1$ of length $\leq k^2$ such that $\delta ( q_1 , w_1 ) = \delta ( p , w_1 ) = p$.
- Note that $q_2^\prime = \delta ( q_2 , w_1 )$ and $p$ are routable to $p$, and so by the above there is a word $w_2$ of length $\leq k^2$ such that $\delta ( q_2^\prime , w_2 ) = \delta ( p , w_2 ) = p$.  Note, then, that $\delta ( q_2 , w_1 w_2 ) = \delta ( p , w_1 w_2 ) = p$, and also $\mathrm{length} (w_1 w_2 ) \leq 2 k^2$.
- Continue in this fashion for all the other states of $M$.